# IOS Safari: positioned absolute child randomly disappears inside positioned fixed parent with transform

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-position, css-transforms

I have drawer animated mobile menu with scrollable navigation and fixed footer.
Since fixed element inside transformed element is impossible according to an old issue I applied absolute position to the footer and apply scroll to the navigation container.
The problem is that on IOS 12.1 footer randomly disappears.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <nav class="nav">...</nav>
  <footer class="footer">Some footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  &.menu-open {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 65px;
}
```

**UPD**
I knew two working fixes:
 1. change transform animation property to left, but thats less performant
 2. set nav bottom to 65px to not overlap with footer but that's not answers why it's happening

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/only_dimon/vnb491Lc/7/)

Comment: would it be possible to add an example of what you want to achieve (maybe a sketch)?

Comment: @RobertBruno Fiddle was added